# How do I document an optional QueryString parameter in ASP.NET WebApi Help Pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-helppages

The ASP.Net Web Api Help Pages seem to automatically determine if a parameter is in the Request Uri or Body.  How can I document option parameters that are QueryString parameters?

For example I have may have a RESTful Url such as

```
[GET] api/Books?relatedToBookId=xx
```

Where "relatedToBookId" is an optional queryString parameter.

Normally the parameters that are FromUri or FromBody are put into the comments as

```
<param name="variableName">blah blah</param>
```

Answer (score 11):

You could do the following and your optional query string parameter info would show up in the HelpPage.

In the below code `relatedToBookId` is an optional parameter coming from Query String.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets list of books
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="relatedToBookId">Your description here</param>
    /// <returns>returns list of books</returns>
    public IEnumerable<Book> GetBooks(int? relatedToBookId = null)
```

Also, if you would like to mention about this parameter being optional, you can do the following:

- Go to the installed file (Areas/HelpPage/Views/Help/DisplayTemplates/Parameters.cshtml)
- Update the condition related to `case ApiParameterSource.FromUri` to the following:

  `case ApiParameterSource.FromUri:
     <p>Define this parameter in the request <b>URI</b>.</p>
     if(parameter.ParameterDescriptor.IsOptional)
     {
       <p>This parameter is <b>optional</b>.</p>
     }
     break;`

Comment: Thank you, Kiran! Is there any way to have two separate help pages: e.g. one for "api/Books" and one for "api/Books?relatedToBookId=xx"?